# Setting values into a CellVariable

Tags: python, fipy

I have the following function:

```
def setupSinkGrid_(self, sinkCoords,mesh,x,y,z,patchSize=1)   :
        sinkGrid = CellVariable(name="source", mesh=mesh, value=0)
        sinkGrid.setValue(0.)

        for pos,v in sinkCoords.iteritems():
            sinkGrid.setValue(v, where=(z > pos[0]-patchSize) & (z < pos[0]+patchSize) & (y > pos[1]-patchSize) & (y < pos[1]+patchSize) & (x > pos[2]-patchSize) & (x < pos[2]+patchSize))

        return sinkGrid
```

Where mesh,x,y, and z are previously defined as:

```
 mesh=Grid3D(dx=dx,dy=dy,nx=nx,ny=ny, dz=dz, nz=nz)

 phi=CellVariable(name="solutionvariable",mesh=mesh,value=0.)

 x, y, z = mesh.cellCenters
```

And sinkCoords is a dictionary of coordinates to values. Eg: `{(1,2,3) => 4}` to indicate the value at 1,2,3 is 4.

The idea is to map each such coordinate onto the sinkGrid.

The problem is as I debug, that I find each sink value mapped to multiple positions "close to" the actual target. After the first iteration( `pos = <type 'tuple'>: (16, 16, 2)`) of the loop, I get:

```
[np.unravel_index(i,(20,20,20)) for i,x in enumerate(list(sinkGrid)) if x > 0]
```

which returns a value of 25 set at 8 distinct indices.

```
0 = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>: (15, 15, 1)
1 = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>: (15, 15, 2)
2 = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>: (15, 16, 1)
3 = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>: (15, 16, 2)
4 = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>: (16, 15, 1)
5 = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>: (16, 15, 2)
6 = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>: (16, 16, 1)
7 = {tuple} <type 'tuple'>: (16, 16, 2)
```

My observation is these are always "lower" coordinates but:

1) Why just on some neighbours? Why don't I get the full moore neighbourhood then?

2) Why just on the neighbours that are lower in at least one dimension?

3) What is causing this? Is it just some rouding error. If so should I use `patchSize-k` or something similar?

Comment: There are two commas in the argument list for `setupSinkGrid_`: `z,,patchSize=1`

Comment: Typo in copying the code, I fixed it in the question, but the problem persists.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I strongly suspect this behavior depends on the values of `dx`, `dy`, `dz`, and `patchSize`. Moreover, I don't understand where your output is coming from at all.

Comment: I'll try to provide that asap. nx,ny,nz are 20 (mine is a 20x20x20 grid), dx,dy,dz is 1. The resulting sinkGrid is a 20x20x20 array. What the where parameter in setValue seems to do is create a an 8000x1 array of booleans which, when unraveled, corresponds to the 20x20x20 grid. It seems that the strict inequalities in the where clause (>, <) are still somehow allowing for adjacent positions to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `x`, `y`, and `z` are the coordinates of the cell centers, which are at ((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (1.5, 0.5, 0.5), ...).

`(16, 16, 2) +/- 1` will then include the cells at:

```
(15.5, 15.5, 1.5)
(15.5, 15.5, 2.5)
(15.5, 16.5, 1.5)
(15.5, 16.5, 2.5)
(16.5, 15.5, 1.5)
(16.5, 15.5, 2.5)
(16.5, 16.5, 1.5)
(16.5, 16.5, 2.5)
```

You have two choices:

1. Supply `sinkCoords` that correspond to cell centers, e.g., `(15.5, 15.5, 1.5`
2. Limit `patchSize` to half the cell dimension

Item 2 is probably a good idea, regardless.

You'll need to ensure you're accounting or the entire range, e.g., `(z > pos[0]-patchSize) & (z <= pos[0]+patchSize)`, otherwise you stand a good chance of not finding any cells.

Comment: That seems to work thanks. I find it easier to directly create the Boolean grid though, that seems still to work. What do you think?

Comment: for pos,v in sinkCoords.iteritems():
            tmpGrid = [False for _ in range(8000)]
            i = np.ravel_multi_index([pos[0], pos[1], pos[2]],(20,20,20))
            tmpGrid[i] = True
            sinkGrid.setValue(v,where=tmpGrid)